# getting interactive, multiple line, formatted input from stdin in bash

Tags: bash, user-interface, stdin

I want to be able to interactively get output from the terminal in a way similar to a hereDOC.  Ie I want the user to be able to type multiple lines, then have that information passed into a file with all the formatting maintained.  Something like this.

```
echo  "Type your message below. To finish the letter type DONE by itself on a line"
file=mktmp
cat << DONE > $file
```

obviously this doesn't work, because the EOF is found before DONE. I thought about passing the user to something like VIM, but my less computer savy coworkers have a hard time with vim/emacs/nano.

Comment: Use `$EDITOR`, and your coworkers can set `EDITOR=their-editor-of-choice`.

Comment: Reading directly from standard input is going to be far less user-friendly than any editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an editor; standard input is just a stream of bytes, not an editor. However, you don't have to hard-code a specific editor. `EDITOR` is a standard environment variable meant to allow your script's caller to choose which editor is used.

```
: ${EDITOR:?Please set the environment variable EDITOR to the editor of your choice}
echo "Type your message below, then save and exit your editor."
"$EDITOR" "$file"
```

`EDITOR` is typically set by the user in their shell configuration file, but can be set on-demand when you run your script.

```
$ EDITOR=nano yourScript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I came up with this, but please help me find something better or improve on it.

```
echo  "Type your message below, to finish the letter press CTL+D"
mapfile message
file=`mktemp`
for x in `seq 0 ${#message[@]}`
        do printf "${message[$x]}" >> $file
done
cat $file
```